# Robolectric Android- testing input on a editTextField

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, robolectric

Hi i am writing a unit test in android using the robolectric framework and i am trying to test a scenario where keys from a keyboard are inputing in a textfield to test the validation of

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

defined in the xml file for the editTextField.

I tried to use the following code below but it doesnt seem to input anything into the editTextField even though it is valid dispatch keys i am passing to the edittext.

```
editTextFirst.setFocusable(true);
    editTextFirst.requestFocus();

    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A,0));
    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A,0));

    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B,0));
    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B,0));

    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C,0));
    editTextFirst.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C,0));

    assertTrue(editTextFirst.length() == 3);
```

The size of the editText should now be 3 and contain ABC but it doesnt? its  empty

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
editTextFirst.setText("ABC"):
```